# Hybrid applications

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid

I am a beginner to hybrid app development. I know there are Ionic version 1 and 2(unofficial release). There is also a Angular JS version 1 and 2 (unofficial release).  my questions is  Can I use Angular js  2 with Ionic version 1 instead of Angular JS 1?

Comment: Your information is incorrect. Both Angular as Ionic has a stable v2.0 release. To reply on your question: Angular 2 can NOT be used with Ionic 1 because Ionic is build on top of Angular.

Comment: thanks for your response